# Defining multiple encrypted parameters

Tags: javascript, php, encryption

I have encrypted parameters in my url, for example:

Encrypted

```
example.com/?auth= *****"encrypted data here including other parameters like &username=helloworld&date=today"*****
example.com/?auth=*****WlJWm3+Sbv6P326v8L59gJyrCmnsjMUOa0sUw0WSPEA=*****
```

Decrypted

```
example.com/?auth=*****succes&username=helloworld&date=today*****
```

I would like to do is define those usernames without showing the decrypted version on the client side. If the parameters would not be decrypted i know i can use

```
$username=$_GET['username'];
```

but now since the parameter + variable is encrypted i think i can not use it. What would be the best way to define a decrypted parameter without showing it in the url? I thought it myself and it might be possible with recognizing the & and = and have some script that recognizes, for example, the  username because its between & and = and the hello world because its between the = and &, however I am not familiar with this type of coding.

Comment: What's so secret about a username that it must be encrypted?

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you use a POST request to send authentication information. POST request will still send the parameter you need without showing it to the user.

I assume you are trying to create a login function and obtain the user's username and password.

so your login form will probably look like this

```
<form method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="username"/>
    <input type="password" name="password"/>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

so after the form submit, you can get the username and password parameter in PHP like so:

```
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
```